# How to 'ask' all turtles in a list

Tags: netlogo

I would like to use `ask` to loop over all of my turtles, but I do **not** want the order to be random. My solution is to add all of the turtles to a list, sorted by their ID, and then loop over this list:

```
let sorted-turtles sort-on [who] turtles
foreach sorted-turtles [ 
  x -> ask x [ ; x is the turtle
    ; do something
  ] 
]
```

That works correctly, but **vastly** slows down my model.

My question is: is this the best way to ask all the turtles to do something in a pre-defined order?

I have tried using `ask` on the list directly (e.g. `ask sorted-turtles [ print who ]` but NetLogo says that `ask` needs an agentset rather than a list.

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can use `sort turtles` instead of `sort-on [who] turtles`. It does the same thing, but it's shorter and more idiomatic. Not sure if it's faster, though (it might help a *little* bit).

The `foreach sorted-turtles [ x -> ask x [ ... ] ]` pattern should be fast enough. It's the list creation that is costly.

The main thing you can do to improve the speed of your model is thus to store the sorted list of turtles in a global variable and reuse that list instead of re-sorting every time.

That would only work, however, if you're not constantly creating and/or killing turtles, it which case you would have to re-create the sorted list every time.

Comment: "...to recreate the sorted list" or update the list. For example, if you'd create a new turtle, insert it into the correct position in the already sorted list.

Comment: @mattsap Good point. Insertions are easy, because they would presumably happen at the end of the list (thus being O(1)), but deletions would be trickier because you have to scan the list for the right agent, which is O(n). Or maybe you could leave the dead agents in the list and add a check for `!= nobody` in the loop, but that could become unmanageable if lots of agents are created/killed... depending on the situation, it may or may not be worth it...

Comment: if I recall correctly, `sort turtles` doesn't actually have to sort the turtles, since they're in sorted order already internally

Comment: Thanks! You're right it was the list creation that took some time (I should have tested that). `sort turtles` is much nicer as well.